# How to get UIImage to send new image and not original image to server

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, quartz-2d

The user picks an image with picker and the following code manipulates the image

```
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; 
    _imageView.image = image;
    _imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    _imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    _imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    _imageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

When I send imageView to the server it is sending the original image and not the new image.  I am guessing this is because UIImageView does not actually change the image but is just making on the fly visual changes to the original image.

Can someone lead me in the right direction as to either what I need to learn in order to make permanent changes to an image/create new image or is there a simple way to make these changes I've made permanent?

Thanks

Comment: What changes are you referring to? What "new image" and "original image" do you mean?

Comment: The original image is never modified in the code snippet provided.  The only thing modified is the container that holds the image.  It's like putting a picture in a frame.  Once you take it out of the frame (and upload it to a server), it's still the same picture.

Comment: nhgrif exactly what I thought was happening.  What do I need to learn about in order to make changes to the actual image?  I see a lot of information about making changes to UIImageView but not about changing the actual image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you talking about getting a new image like it appear on screen (with the corner radius set etc etc) so you might want to test some like that :

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.image.size);

[self.imageView drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.imageView.frame afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```